Type of position in RandomAccessFile is long but it is int in MappedByteBuffer
The RandomAccessFile class in Java uses type long in methods getFilePointer(), length(), seek(), and setLength().
However, if I want to manipulate this file via MappedByteBuffer, I can only specify the Buffer's position as an int.
Is this a feature or an API shortcoming in JDK? (Very likely, it's the former but not sure why.)
Is downcasting the file pointer from long to an int Buffer position the only way around?

As I read it FileChannel.map which creates the mapping restricts the size to Integer.MAX_VALUE so an int is all that is required for a position in the buffer. From Java 22 onwards you can also map to a MemorySegment which doesn't have that size restriction.

So essentially, Java 21 (which is what I'm using) does have Integer.MAX_VALUE as a limitation. Fair enough, seems like downcasting for now is my only option.

@greg-449 If you can post that as a reply, I'll mark it as the final answer.

The FileChannel.map call which creates the mapping has long size but the Javadoc says:

The size of the region to be mapped; must be non-negative and no
greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE

So an int value is sufficent to set the position inside the map.
For Java 22 onwards the Foreign Functions and Memory support adds an alternative version of FileChannel.map which returns a MemorySegment which doesn't have the size restriction.

Worth noting that this is not just a limitation of the map operation but ByteBuffer’s capacity and limit are restricted to int anyway, so a method returning a ByteBuffer can’t map to a region larger than that. Since the position must be between zero and the limit, it‘s obviously restricted to values int the int range.

But this doesn’t mean that you can’t use mapped buffers for larger positions. You just have to adapt the start position of the mapped region when mapping and create more than one mapped buffer if needed.
